# Defining vertex of a polygon using mplPath in python

Tags: python, list, function, path

I was defining a function to see if the value returned by the list(car_coord) is found inside a polygon. The list(car_coord) is returned in real-time and the list looks like,

car_coord=[[(847.88,1109.476)],[842.3852,1050.5856]]. These points are in the polygon, but the function returns False. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
def points_inside_polygon(car_coord): 
   poly = [800,1300,780,1250]         #vertex of the polygon
   bbPath = mplPath.Path(np.array([[poly[0],poly[1]],[poly[1],poly[2]],[poly[2],poly[3]],[poly[3],poly[0]]]))
   if bbPath.contains_point((car_coord)):
       print 'yes'
       return True
   else:
      print 'no'
      return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For geometric objects ,you should use `shapely`

Take a look

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely
Then try something like this

```
from shapely import geometry

poly = geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in pointList])
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I am using an older version of python where shapely module is not supported. Can u suggest where am making mistake in the above code?

Comment: i was able to find the mistake.